# how can I save variable in a file?

Tags: java, arrays, io, persistence

is there a way I can save a variable for example an array of colors and then retrieve it. Im making a board game and i need to be able to save at any given time. If it doesn't work like that, can any give me any other recommendation in what can I use?.

Comment: You should look into serialization.

Comment: Serialization is maybe a bit too heavy for a simple task like that. Take a look at java [file i/o](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). I'll have to -1 though because this question could have been solved with a simple google search. Sorry. If you *did* mean something like serialization though, edit the post and I'll take it back.

Comment: It all depends upon which element's array are you going to save..If the element is serializable then you can use Serialization.. Else go with Curt's answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to write objects which implement the `Serializable` interface.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("my.save");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(colorsArray);
```

Of course, loading is also possible in the same way:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("my.save");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
colorsArray = (Color[]) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: +1 You should mention DataInputStream and DataOutputStream for primitives as well.

Comment: I think `ObjectOutputStream` provides the same methods for writing primitives as `DataOutputStream` does. But if the OP does not require the additional capabilities, the lighter `DataOutputStream` would of course also be suitable for writing save game data.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the XML serialization utilities.   If your "variable" is a class instance (or contained in one), this should make saving the values quite simple.

If it's not, you'll have to figure out a way to write out the variable's values, and parse it back, from a string so that you can save it to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of ways to serialize data.  Here is one (lifted from a small project I have open), using `ArrayList` as the data container, `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder` for serialization, and puts them in a Zip for good measure.

```
public void loadComments() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File f = getPropertiesFile();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fis);
    ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();

    while (!entry.getName().equals(COMMENTS_ENTRY_NAME)) {
        entry = zis.getNextEntry();
    }
    InputSource is = new InputSource(zis);
    XMLDecoder xmld = new XMLDecoder(is);
    comments = (ArrayList<Comment>) xmld.readObject();
    try {
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CommentAssistant.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void saveComments() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    CommentComparator commentComparator = new CommentComparator();
    Collections.sort(comments, commentComparator);

    File f = getPropertiesFile();
    System.out.println("Save to: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
    File p = f.getParentFile();
    if (!p.exists() && !p.mkdirs()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Could not create settings directory: "
                + p.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(COMMENTS_ENTRY_NAME);
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);

    XMLEncoder xmld = new XMLEncoder(zos);
    xmld.writeObject(comments);
    xmld.flush();
    xmld.close();
}
```